# ¿Es correcto usar dos "comos" y decir "tanto como X como como Y"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, conjunciones

Supongamos que queremos utilizar la expresión *Tanto X como Y*, por ejemplo:

> Me gustan **tanto** el chocolate **como** los garbanzos

Es decir, que me refiero a ambas cosas por igual. Vale, esto me suena bien y funciona.

Supongamos ahora que esta *X* y esta *Y* son algo más complejas e incluyen la preposición *como*. Por ejemplo, si quiero indicar que me gusta ir en coche ya sea conduciendo o de copiloto, podría decir...

> Me gusta ir en coche **tanto** como conductor **como** como copiloto

o

> Te quiero **tanto** como amigo **como** como amante

En *... como como amante*, el primer *como* tiene función de conjunción en la expresión *tanto X como Y*, mientras que el segundo hace la función de preposición que introduce la "finalidad".

Dicho en voz alta yo hago una pausa tras el primer *como*, pero por escrito se ve fatal. Así que ahí es donde surge la duda: ¿es correcto usar dos *como*s consecutivos, pero de distinto tipo gramatical en este caso y tener *como como copiloto*?

Comment: Me parece curioso que no entiendo la pregunta. Para mi no tienen ningún sentido usar dos veces 'como'.  Pero sabiendo de quien viene la pregunta, me pregunto qué es lo que no entiendo? Se me ocurre que en inglés uno podría decir "I like to go in a car as a driver as well as like a co-pilot". El primer 'como' es 'as well as' y el segundo sería 'like'.  ¿Es ese el ejemplo? si es así @VladimirNu tampoco entendió la pregunta y su respuesta no es válida.

Comment: @DGaleano exactamente como dices. Las frases serían algo así como _I like to go... both as a driver and as a co-pilot_ y _I love you both as a friend and as a lover_. Edito para explicarlo mejor, ¡gracias!

Comment: @DGaleano perdona, en el comentario anterior no fui del todo preciso. _as a X as well as like a Y_ no sería exactamente la traducción, sino, como indiqué en mi comentario, _both as a X and as a Y_. Es decir, tanto X como Y son propiedades iguales. Qué mal me explico jaja

Comment: Ok. Entonces me parece que usar los dos 'como' es correcto si lo que quieres expresar es algo como 'cuasi-amante' (like a lover) de lo contrario no necesitas sino el primer 'como' para decir "as well as" y el segundo 'como' es equivocado. Para mi el significado cambia con el uso del segundo 'como'

Comment: Lo mismo ocurre con *que* en algunos casos. Se me ocurre la expresión *mejor que sobre y no que falte*, donde si se sigue la estructura *mejor A que B*, tendría que ser *?mejor que sobre que que falte*. Curiosamente, yo oí distintas versiones de gramática discutible (mejor que sobre a que falte, mejor que sobre que no que falte), pero nunca la del *que* duplicado. Estoy con Vladimir en que omitir uno de los *comos* sería la mejor opción, e incluso me parece haberlo oído o leído por alguna parte. Les acabo de enviar un correo a la RAE, a ver qué nos dicen.

Comment: Ya que hacen comparaciones con el inglés, se puede tener un efecto similar en ese idioma. Por ejemplo, esta frase en una nota the *The Independent*: *Sylvia Plath survives **as** a legend **as** much **as as** a poet*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Es perfectamente válido](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=s3kpSlOhuD6v706948), tal y como puede leerse en la entrada de *como* del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> **como**. Palabra átona que, como tal, debe escribirse sin tilde, a diferencia del adverbio interrogativo o exclamativo cómo (→ cómo).
>   Puede funcionar como adverbio, como conjunción y como preposición.
>
> 2. Conjunción
>
> b) En correlación con el adverbio tanto forma una conjunción compuesta
>   discontinua de valor copulativo (...). En este tipo de correlaciones,
>   no sería gramaticalmente incorrecta la expresión conjunta del *como*
>   conjuntivo y del *como* modal, en oraciones del tipo *El sustantivo
>   puede funcionar tanto como sujeto como como complemento directo*; no
>   obstante, en esos casos, para evitar la cacofonía, suele preferirse el
>   uso de otras estructuras, como la coordinación copulativa o
>   disyuntiva, o la sustitución del como conjuntivo por *cuanto* (→
>   cuanto, 1.3.4 y 1.3.5): *El sustantivo puede funcionar como sujeto y
>   como complemento directo*; *El sustantivo puede funcionar como sujeto
>   o como complemento directo*; *El sustantivo puede funcionar tanto como
>   sujeto cuanto como complemento directo*.

El único problema puede ser la cacofonía, pero eso se puede evitar cambiando algunas palabras, que para eso tenemos un idioma rico:

> - Me gusta ir en coche, ya sea como conductor, ya sea como copiloto.
> - Me gusta ir en coche, tanto de conductor como de copiloto.
> - Me gusta ir en coche, tanto como conductor cuanto como copiloto. *(Versión propuesta por el artículo del DPD enlazado.)*

Esto me recuerda a aquella famosa frase que decía:

> *¿Cómo como? Como como como.*

Alguien podría argumentar que en esta frase algunos *como* son verbos y otros *adverbios*, pero es que en el ejemplo del coche pasa lo mismo: el primer *como* (el que va con *tanto*) es una conjunción, y el segundo es una preposición (que significa "en calidad de"). Luego ninguno sobra.

Acepciones de [como](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWAAKF%7C9xWxEd9):

> **(12)** conj. U. con valor copulativo en correlación con tanto. *Detuvieron tanto a los culpables como a los sospechosos.*
>
> **(18)** prep. En calidad de, en concepto de o a modo de. *Asistió a la boda como testigo. Usan esta banqueta como mesa.*

Comment: En la pregunta el primer 'como' es en 'calidad de' pero el segundo significa 'parecido a'. En la respuesta queda faltando este último significado. En mi comentario a la pregunta @fedorqui valida que el equivalente en inglés seria una frase con "as well as" seguida de "like". fedorqui siempre le gusta hacer _tricky questions_

Comment: Muy bueno el ejemplo del _como ^5_ ;) Sí, obviamente es mejor reformular la frase, pero tenía la curiosidad de saber si era correcto usar dos veces la misma palabra. El hecho de que uno sea conjunción y el otro preposición parece que clarifica la discusión, en cuanto a que cumplen funciones distintas.

Comment: @DGaleano en el segundo ejemplo, el segundo _como_ también significa "en calidad de". En este caso, "te quiero en calidad de amante". Si te fijas en la corrección de fedorqui, el ejemplo en inglés en realidad no usa _like_ sino _as... as..._: _I like you both as a friend and as a lover_.

Comment: "...en calidad de **como** amante" o de una manera menos confusa "te quiero tanto como amigo como cuasi-amante"

Comment: Esta es la forma que yo lo diría, con unas comas y agregando *ya sea*. Pero ponerlo con doble *como*, la verdad jamás lo había visto.

Comment: En caso de que quieras referencias: DPD, 2b: "En este tipo de correlaciones, no sería gramaticalmente incorrecta la expresión conjunta del *como* conjuntivo y del *como* modal, en oraciones del tipo *El sustantivo puede funcionar tanto como sujeto como como complemento directo*; no obstante, en esos casos, para evitar la cacofonía, suele preferirse el uso de otras estructuras, como la coordinación copulativa o disyuntiva, o la sustitución del *como* conjuntivo por *cuanto*".

Comment: @Yay ¡gracias, no se me había ocurrido mirar en el DPD! ¡Respuesta actualizada!

Answer (score -2):

No es correcto, y tampoco tiene sentido.

> Me gusta ir en coche/carro/auto tanto como conductor como copiloto

Es perfectamente correcta y cumple la misma función que lo que intentas hacer. La comparación ya la estás haciendo así que no es necesario (ni correcto) agregar otra.

Nota: La diferenciación de coche/carro/auto es con fines de diferencias regionales, ya que en distintos países se dice de distinta forma.

Comment: Nótese que lo mismo no me expliqué bien: son dos _como_, pero cada uno de un tipo distinto; uno es preposición y el otro conjunción. Si puedes, échale una ojeada a mi actualización.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, quien votó negativamente podría aportar algún comentario para que Vladimir pudiera saber en qué se basa. Probablemente sea por cómo se entendía la pregunta inicialmente.

Comment: @fedorqui no importa mucho cómo te hayas explicado, la frase propuesta en esta respuesta simplemente "no es correcta ni tiene sentido". El segundo *como* solo se puede entender como parte de la construcción *tanto ... como*, por lo que en la comparación quedan dos cosas de naturaleza distinta: por un lado *como conductor*, y por el otro *copiloto*.

Comment: @fedorqui La respuesta propuesta por Carlos Alejo es mucho mejor. Definitivamente lo que quise decir es que *no se debería* construir la frase de esa manera, pero sí se puede formular de otra, como lo propone Carlos. Yo sólo me limité a decir que no se podía :)