# ¿Es correcto usar dos preposiciones iguales seguidas?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

Tengo una duda con respecto al uso de preposiciones en la que mi cerebro lingüístico me dice una cosa, y mi cerebro lógico me dice otra.

Os lo explico con un ejemplo.

El verbo **depender** viene siempre seguido de la preposición **de**, que introduce un [complemento de régimen verbal o suplemento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_de_r%C3%A9gimen). Así:

> Todo depende de su origen.

En este caso, *su origen* es un sintagma nominal que puede ser fácilmente sustituido por una frase que exprese lo mismo de manera perifrástica:

> Su origen = de dónde proviene.

Así, si introducimos esta segunda estructura en la frase inicial, nos queda:

> Todo depende **de de** dónde proviene.

Y efectivamente, *tachán*, tenemos dos hermosas preposiciones idénticas seguidas.

Se pueden crear otros ejemplos similares de manera relativamente simple, incluso con otras preposiciones:

> - No me acuerdo de su propietario --> No me acuerdo **de de** quién es eso.
> - Pepe se refiere a esa persona --> Pepe se refiere **a a** quien llamaba María.
> - Soñé con mi marido --> Soñé **con con** quien me casé.

El problema de todo esto es que esas frases me suenan fatal, y, sin embargo, no le veo el fallo a la lógica para llegar a ellas. Por otra parte, he prestado especial atención últimamente a cómo lo dicen en medios de comunicación (por ejemplo) y, en casos similares, usan una única preposición.

Así pues, las preguntas:

- ¿Es esto correcto? ¿O incorrecto? ¿O correcto pero desaconsejado?
- ¿Está esto recogido/reglado en algún sitio?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Es correcto usar dos “comos” y decir “tanto como X como como Y”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17462/1674)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no es correcto, según se indica en la *Nueva gramática* de la RAE, [sección 43.8p](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pGogVlDZcqzSqJ,,):

> Tiende a evitarse la repetición de la preposición cuando coinciden la elegida por el predicado principal y la seleccionada por el predicado de la subordinada. Se rechazan, pues, construcciones como **Eso depende de de quién quieras hablar*, aunque contengan dos preposiciones justificadas sintácticamente: la elegida por *depender* y la seleccionada por *hablar*.

Pero ojo, que la solución *recomendada* no es quitar un "de" y ya está. Más adelante dice:

> Para sustituir la opción inviable **Eso depende de de quién quieras hablar*, no se considera recomendable superponer las dos preposiciones en una sola o elidir una de ellas (*Eso depende de quién quieras hablar*). Una forma de evitar ambas estructuras es elegir un grupo nominal que contenga una relativa con antecedente expreso, como en *Eso depende de quién sea la persona de quien quieras hablar*.

Es decir, que aunque fusionar ambas preposiciones no sería incorrecto (pues no lo marca con *), lo recomendado es cambiar la frase para separarlas.

Comment: Otras soluciones posibles: *Eso depende.  ¿De quién quieres hablar? / Eso depende del sujeto al que escojas*.

Comment: Pero fíjate que dice que «tiende a evitarse» y luego en 44.7u «se suele omitir una cuando…», pero en ningún caso dice que es definitivamente imposible.  Aunque, eso dicho, sí que me pregunto en qué situación sería posible o incluso aconsejable usar ambas (ya que como dice, sintácticamente no hay problema, es solo una cuestión de cacofonía)

Comment: Y he encontrado un ejemplo (no moderno): https://books.google.com/books?id=jpGc_F1GOSQC&pg=PA429&dq=%22de+de+qui%C3%A9n%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfy5LE5K3XAhUIdiYKHemcBC04ChDoAQg_MAM#v=onepage&q=%22de%20de%20qui%C3%A9n%22&f=false

Comment: @guifa no sé si en todos los casos pero en el ejemplo que ha puesto walen dice: *Para sustituir la opción inviable*. Ahí yo entiendo que esa construcción no es posible.