# 2 prepositions running together

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

I came across the following sentence in the [Spanish dict website](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/tener%20orgullo):

No hay nada malo en tener orgullo de donde vienes.

AFAIK there is a preposition attached to the phrase "tener orgullo", i.e., "tener orgullo de/en algo". Also there is a preposition attached to the clause "de donde vienes", so when they are put together why didn't I see 2 prepositions running together, like:

? No hay nada malo en tener orgullo de de donde vienes.

or

? No hay nada malo en tener orgullo en de donde vienes.

Are the two hypothetical sentences above right, or acceptable but weird, or simply wrong?

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23114/es-correcto-usar-dos-preposiciones-iguales-seguidas

Comment: @Gustavson From the link, it seems that "tener orgullo de de donde vienes" is incorrect, but "tener orgullo en de donde vienes" is OK, right?

Comment: The point is that "tener orgullo" is not followed by "en".  The best thing is to say: No hay nada malo en tener orgullo del lugar de donde vienes. Or still better: No hay nada malo en estar/sentirse orgulloso del lugar de donde vienes.